# How to disable or enable touchpad by linux terminal on ubuntu or debian based OS?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, linux-terminal

Any idea of how to enable or disable touchpad using the linux terminal  ?
I'm using ubuntu 18.04

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in an Xorg session, you could use xinput to disable it.

from a terminal execute:

```
xinput list
```

find the id number, and from a terminal;

```
xinput set-prop id_number "Device Enabled" 0
```

Another option would be to unload the kernel module for the device, but this varies from device to device. but if you knew the kernel module / driver;

```
sudo modprobe -r touch_device
```

it's also possible to unbind devices. For example, I do this for the camera on my laptop;

```
echo '1-4' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

so if you knew the bus / location of the touch device you could disable it this way too.